# Sleep for exact time in python

Tags: python, windows, sleep

I need to wait for about 25ms in one of my functions. Sometimes this function is called when the processor is occupied with other things and other times it has the processor all to itself.

I've tried `time.sleep(.25)` but sometimes its actually 25ms and other times it takes much longer.  Is there a way to sleep for an exact amount of time regardless of processor availability?

Comment: no, not in a non-realtime system

Comment: "*about* 25ms"... `sleep` is perfect for that task.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you're working with a [preemptive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) operating system, there's no way you can guarantee that your process will be able to have control of the CPU in 25ms.

If you'd still like to try, it would be better to have a busy loop that polls until 25ms has passed.  Something like this might work:

```
import time
target_time = time.clock() + 0.025
while time.clock() < target_time:
    pass
```

Comment: Why is busy waiting better here?  Doesn't this depend on the length of the time slices assigned to each process?  If the standard time slice was 25 ms, busy waiting would certainly be worse, since it would pretty much *guarantee* that the processor will be unavailable after waiting if there are more active processes than cores.

Comment: According to my understanding, if you `time.sleep` for 25ms, the thread will be taken off the active queue until 25ms have gone by, after which it will be moved to the active queue and then executed at some point in the future.  If you busy-wait, you stay on the active queue.

Comment: If you have to wait and excecute something every 0.025 secs repeteadly, you can update `target_time` like this: `target_time += 0.025` instead of `target_time = time.clock() + 0.025`. This way, you won't be "losing" time between waitings.

Comment: In Python 3.8 and newer, `time.clock()` has been replaced with `time.perf_counter()`.

Answer (score 6):

0.25 seconds are 250 ms, not 25.  Apart from this, there is no way to wait for *exactly* 25 ms on common operating systems – you would need some real-time operating system.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** in Windows 10 this nonsense seems unnecessary. Try it like so:

```
>>> from time import sleep
>>> import timeit
>>> '%.2f%% overhead' % (timeit.timeit('sleep(0.025)', number=100, globals=globals()) / 0.025 - 100)
'0.29% overhead'
```

.29%, or thereabout, is fairly low overhead, and usually more than accurate enough.

***Previous Windows versions*** will by default have a sleep resolution of 55 msecs, which means your sleep call will take somewhere between 25 and 55 msecs. To get the sleep resolution down to 1 millisecond you need to set the resolution used by Windows by calling [`timeBeginPeriod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
import ctypes
winmm = ctypes.WinDLL('winmm')
winmm.timeBeginPeriod(1)
```

Answer (score 5):

What system are you on? If you're on Windows you may want to do something like this for exact timing:

```
import ctypes
kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

# This sets the priority of the process to realtime--the same priority as the mouse pointer.
kernel32.SetThreadPriority(kernel32.GetCurrentThread(), 31)
# This creates a timer. This only needs to be done once.
timer = kernel32.CreateWaitableTimerA(ctypes.c_void_p(), True, ctypes.c_void_p())
# The kernel measures in 100 nanosecond intervals, so we must multiply .25 by 10000
delay = ctypes.c_longlong(.25 * 10000)
kernel32.SetWaitableTimer(timer, ctypes.byref(delay), 0, ctypes.c_void_p(), ctypes.c_void_p(), False)
kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(timer, 0xffffffff)
```

This code will pretty much guarentee your process will sleep .25 seconds. Watch out though- you may want to lower the priority to 2 or 3 unless it's **absolutely critical** that this sleeps for .25 seconds. Certainly don't change the priority too high for a user-end product.

Comment: Very old answer I know....   but any chance you know how to make this work on Windows10 + Python3?

Comment: `kernel32.WaitForSingleObject` or `kernel32.Sleep` is not more accurate than `time.sleep`. It is about setting the timer resolution, the process priority, and other code running along side. It cannot get more accurate than ~1 ms.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution for accurate timings and delay is to use the perf_counter() function from module time. Especially useful in windows as time.sleep is not accurate in milliseconds. See below example where function accurate_delay creates a delay in millisecond.

```
import time


def accurate_delay(delay):
    ''' Function to provide accurate time delay in millisecond
    '''
    _ = time.perf_counter() + delay/1000
    while time.perf_counter() < _:
        pass


delay = 10
t_start = time.perf_counter()
print('Wait for {:.0f} ms. Start: {:.5f}'.format(delay, t_start))

accurate_delay(delay)

t_end = time.perf_counter()
print('End time: {:.5f}. Delay is {:.5f} ms'.
      format(t_end, 1000*(t_end - t_start)))

sum = 0
ntests = 1000
for _ in range(ntests):
    t_start = time.perf_counter()
    accurate_delay(delay)
    t_end = time.perf_counter()
    print('Test completed: {:.2f}%'.format(_/ntests * 100), end='\r', flush=True)
    sum = sum + 1000*(t_end - t_start) - delay

print('Average difference in time delay is {:.5f} ms.'.format(sum/ntests))
```

Answer (score 2):

What you intend to do is a real time application. Python (and probably the OS you are using) is not intended to program this kind of applications, where time restriction is so strict.

In order for you to achieve what you are looking for you need a RTOS (Real Time Operating System) and develop your application using a suitable programming language (usually C) following RT best practises.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/time.html#time.sleep) of the sleep method:

> Suspend execution for the given number of seconds. The argument may be
>   a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time. The
>   actual suspension time **may be less** than that requested because any
>   caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that
>   signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time **may be longer
>   than** requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of
>   other activity in the system.

The fact is that it depends on your underlying OS.