# calling a function at an exact time

Tags: time, python-2.7

I'm just learning Python. Out of some weird impulse, I am trying to create a [decimal clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time). This decimal clock divides the day into 10 Hours per day, 100 minutes per hour, 100 seconds per minute. There are 100,000 seconds in a decimal day; 86,400 in "archaic" time. Every 1 second of archaic time equals ~1.157 seconds of new, improved decimal time (assuming I've gotten that little bit of math correct.)

The problem I am running into is that in order for the clock to tick away the decimal seconds accurately and sequentially, I need a function to fire every 1.157 seconds as exactly as possible.  I have a calling function, `DeciTimeCaller`, which loops infinitely, calling the `decimaltime.time_to_string` method, which converts from archaic time to decimal time and prints the time in decimal hours:min:sec. The calling function then sleeps, `time.sleep(1.157)`, and does it all over.

But because of background processes taking priority (I assume,) the printed time skips seconds here and there.

For example, here's output from about 20 seconds:

```
0:85:92
0:85:93
0:85:95
0:85:96
0:85:97
0:85:99
0:86:00
0:86:01
0:86:03
0:86:04
0:86:05
0:86:07
0:86:08
```

I recognize that Python and Linux don't constitute a real time system and I have tried some suggestions in other threads, e.g. [Sleep for exact time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657734/sleep-for-exact-time-in-python), without success. But I'm thinking there might be some way to fudge this.

So the question is: *Can I get this clock to run like clockwork?*

My code is below. Couple of things to note: I import the threading module because I was trying to work with Events, but I'm not currently using it. I use the decimal module because I thought maybe there was a problem with the precision of floating point values in the conversion. Doesn't seem to make any difference. I also have the timeit module and some commented code where I have been attempting to time the calls.

```
import time
import datetime as dt
import decimal
import threading
import timeit

class decimaltime:
  """ Presents the time of day in Decimal Time 
      10 Hours/day
      100 minutes/hour
      100 seconds/minute
  """
  def time(self, archaic_seconds = 0):
    if archaic_seconds == 0:
      now = decimal.Decimal(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%s.%f'))
      midnight = decimal.Decimal(dt.date.today().strftime('%s.%f'))
      archaic_seconds_from_midnight = decimal.Decimal(now - midnight)
    else:
      archaic_seconds_from_midnight = decimal.Decimal(archaic_seconds)
    return archaic_seconds_from_midnight * decimal.Decimal('1.157')

  def time_to_string(self, decimal_seconds = 0):
    if decimal_seconds == 0:  
      seconds_from_midnight = self.time() 
    else:
      seconds_from_midnight =  decimal.Decimal(decimal_seconds)
    decimal_hour = seconds_from_midnight / 10000
    decimal_minute = (seconds_from_midnight % 10000) / 100
    decimal_second = seconds_from_midnight % 100
    time_string = "%(hour)01d:%(minute)02d:%(second)02d" % {"hour": decimal_hour, "minute": decimal_minute, "second": decimal_second}
    print time_string
    # return time_string

def DeciTimeCaller():
  decitime = decimaltime()
  # t = timeit.Timer(lambda: decitime.time_to_string())
  while True:
    # print t.timeit(1)
    decitime.time_to_string()
    time.sleep(1.157)

DeciTimeCaller()
```

Update:

From Thomas' suggestion below, I modified the code to check the decimal time every 1/10 of a second. If the decimal time has changed, I print out the time. This works like clockwork, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Here's revised `DeciTimeCaller` function:

```
def DeciTimeCaller():
  decitime = decimaltime()
  old_time = decitime.time_to_string()
  while True:
    new_time = decitime.time_to_string()
    if (new_time != old_time): 
      print new_time
      old_time = new_time
    time.sleep(.1667)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite difficult to run a function in a precise frequency.

You could create a function that converts current system time to your decimal time 30 times / second. This way your time is always correct and you will never run out of sync.

Comment: But if I can't run a function with a precise frequency, wouldn't that also exclude being able to run one 30 times/second? Not sure why 30 times/second is significant. Are you thinking of frame rates for video? I was going down that path at one point to see how frame rates are maintained.

Comment: I was thinking about GUI update frame rates. With 30 FPS (just an example!) there will be no notable lag whatsoever. The FPS do not need to be constant that way.

Comment: so I think you're suggesting that rather than trying to set the time at a specific interval, I just set it frequently (30 times per second was suggested rate). And I think that would work, even at a slower rate. I'm going to try it.

Comment: It works! Great idea, Thomas! A minor change to the code got it working perfectly.