# So I want to make a clock in Python that displays both A.M. and P.M

Tags: python

So I have this here.

```
import sys
import os
import time


def clock():
  Minutes = 0
  Hours = 1

while True:
    Minutes += 1

    if Minutes == 60:
        Minutes = 0
        Hours = 2

        if Hours == 12:
            Hours = 1
            Minutes = 0
            break    

            ReadLine = ("\t{0:>2} : {1:>2}\r").format(Hours, Minutes)
            sys.stdout.write(ReadLine)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(60)
            clock()
```

Just for the record, I have made sure that the indentations are correct, they look a little screwy here. And I realize that I have nothing set for A.M./P.M. as of yet.. Any help is appreciated for this noob.
Thank you - Matt.

Edit:

```
   >>> 2: 0 2: 0 2: 0
```

This is what is printing out now, the minutes have not updated. I'm obviously missing something. Once again thanks for any help, and I am sorry if this is a repeat, I have searched for an answer, but none was found. Thanks - Matt.

Edit #2- I figured it out. I used a bit of both of the answers, and whilst I accept the fact that it will be slow it does what I want it to do.

```
     import sys
     import os
     import time


      def clock():
          Minutes = 0
          Hours = 1
          AM_PM = "AM" if Hours < 12 else "P.M"
          while True:
              Minutes += 1

             if Minutes == 60:
                  Minutes = 0
                  Hours += 1

                      if Hours == 24:
                         Hours = 1
                         Minutes = 0
                         break

                        ReadLine = ("\t{:>2} : {:>2} {}\r").format(Hours, Minutes, AM_PM)
                       sys.stdout.write(ReadLine)
                       sys.stdout.flush()
                       time.sleep(60)                
                       clock()
```

You know, it seems no matter how hard I try, I cannot get this darned indentation to look right. Oh well, I hope you can understand it's just tabbed a bit to the right.

Comment: your hour will never reach 12, you don't increase it, but it is set to 2.

Comment: please try to fix the indentation here, we can't understand. does the while loop is inside the `clock` function? does the `clock()` line is inside the loop? inside the function?

Comment: your clock() call is after the infinit `while`-loop and thus Minutes is not initialized

Comment: time.sleep is not guaranteed to exactly sleep for 60 seconds. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657734/sleep-for-exact-time-in-python

Comment: IMHO, it's best to use standard modules (`time`, `datetime`) whenever possible, rather that try to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @Carpetsmoker agreed, of course, but my wheel is so pretty!

Comment: OP: your new code (from edit) will fail on infinite recursion. Sincerely consider my approach before you keep going down this rabbit hole.

Comment: It will fail on infinite recursion... What?

Comment: @Matttheawesome1 You recurse on `clock()` `while True` with no break condition. That's infinite recursion. Of course it's impossible to know when you're actually trying to call `clock` because you're using tabs instead of spaces ([don't do that](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)), I suppose it might be at the root level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code print nothing because you put the code that print to stdout inside the `if` statements. so it would print only when `Minutes == 60` and `Hours == 12` (which will never happend because of you dont increament `Hours` as meantioned in the comments.

try this:

```
import sys
import os
import time


def clock():
    Minutes = 0
    Hours = 1
    ampm = "AM"

    while True:
        Minutes += 1

        if Minutes == 60:
            Minutes = 0
            Hours += 1

        if Hours == 12:
            Hours = 1
            Minutes = 0
            ampm = ("AM" if (ampm == "PM") else "PM")

        ReadLine = ("\t{0:>2} : {1:>2} {2} \r").format(Hours, Minutes,ampm)
        sys.stdout.write(ReadLine)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(60)                
clock()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, unfortunately I just joined so I can't thumbs you up. But your work is appreciated.

Comment: Your clock will always be slow if you use `time.sleep(60)`

Comment: note i fixed a few typos just now. and you can accept if you want

Comment: note that this answer also doesn't address the problem implied in the title (A.M. and P.M.)

Comment: so if I add something like this: 
import time
target_time = time.clock() +60.0s
while time.clock() < target_time:
    pass

It should work?

Comment: I am also aware of the problem adressed in the title, I will be working on that in a minute.

Comment: @Matttheawesome1, it would work, but it will busy your CPU for nothing

Comment: @AdamSmith, Thanks, I've added the AM/PM issue now

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

then = now = datetime.datetime.now()
minutes = 0
hours = 0
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if (now-then).total_seconds() > 60:
        then += datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
        minutes += 1
        if minutes == 60:
            minutes = 0
            hours += 1
        if hours == 24:
            hours = 0
            am_pm = "AM" if hours < 12 else "PM"
        print("{:>2}:{:>02} {}".format((hours+11)%12+1, minutes, am_pm))
```

Note that I do away with `time.sleep` as it's not guaranteed to sleep for exactly the time requested (indeed you will always be running slightly slow by that clock) and instead compare a current time to the last time a minute passed and see if the total seconds are more than 60. If so, increment minutes, if minutes is 60, increment hours and check for rollover and am_pm switch. Afterwards, print the time.

If you're wanting to stretch your legs a little, try implementing it in a class! Ooh ooh, and threading too!

```
import datetime
import threading
import queue

class Clock(object):
    def __init__(self, current_time=None):
        if isinstance(current_time, datetime.datetime):
            hours, minutes = current_time.hour, current_time.minute
        else:
            hours = minutes = 0
        self.hours = hours
        self.minutes = minutes
        self.q = queue.Queue()
    def checkTime(self):
        try:
            self.q.get_nowait() # time has updated, or exception thrown
            self.updateTime()
            self.q.task_done()
        except queue.Empty:
            pass # time hasn't updated
    def updateTime(self, num_mins=1):
        self.minutes += 1
        if self.minutes == 60:
            self.minutes = 0
            self.hours += 1
        if self.hours == 24:
            self.hours = 0
        print(self)
    def minutePassed(self):
        then = datetime.datetime.now()
        while True:
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            if (now-then).total_seconds() > 60:
                then += datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
                self.q.put('_') # put something there, doesn't matter what
    def __str__(self):
        am_pm = "AM" if self.hours < 12 else "PM"
        return "{:>2}:{:>02} {}".format((self.hours+11)%12+1,
                                        self.minutes, am_pm)
    def start(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.minutePassed)
        t.daemon=True
        t.start()
        while True:
            self.checkTime()

clock = Clock(datetime.datetime.now())
clock.start()
```

Comment: >>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Clock.py", line 8, in <module>
    if (now-then).total_seconds > 60:
TypeError: unorderable types: builtin_function_or_method() >

Comment: @Matttheawesome1 oops, `total_seconds` is a function not an attribute. fixed.