# run python scheduler continuously

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def print_time():       
    print "From print_time", time.time()

def print_some_times():
    print time.time()
    s.enter(5, 1, print_time, ())
    s.enter(10, 1, print_time, ())
    s.run()

print_some_times()
```

The above code can be used to execute the `print_time()` function exactly in 5 seconds and 10 seconds.

I want to know that how I could execute `print_time()` function exactly with a 5 second time period continuously(periodically) without stoping.

Comment: Take a look at [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Sounds to me like this is what you are trying to recreate.

Comment: I know about cron jobs. but i am not able to use cron jobs for this task. periodically execution task should be handled by the script itself

Comment: Did you try with `time.sleep()` ?

Comment: Oh.. I see...In order to prevent people from suggesting things like that you should include all of your restrictions/considerations in your post.

Comment: Be aware that when you use sleep you wont get exactly 5seconds but only around 5 seconds and maybe a bit longer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657734/sleep-for-exact-time-in-python

Comment: yeah in this case this will take more than 5 seconds to invoke function. I found another method for this  and posted it as an answer. hope it is useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even though time.sleep() function works it is not much accurate. consider the below code

```
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    print_time()
```

in this case the function always delay execution 5 seconds. assume print_time() function spend 2 seconds for executions. then according to this method print_time() function invokes with a period of 7 seconds( 5 + 2 )

but the answer can be obtained more accurately by doing it via following code

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def print_time(): 
    s.enter(5, 1, print_time, ())  
    print "From print_time", time.time()

def print_some_times():
    print time.time()
    s.enter(5, 1, print_time, ())        
    s.run()

print_some_times()
```

what here happens is when print_time() function is executed. at the very beginning of the print_time() function, another entry to the scheduler queue is added in this case the accuracy is very high

Answer (score 1):

you can use a thread that sleeps 5 seconds:

```
import threading, time

def worker():
    i = 0
    while (True):
        print 'do something ... ' + str(time.time())
        time.sleep(5)
        i += 1
        if i > 5: break

t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
print time.time()
t.start()
print time.time()
```

If you want to run this "forever" - just remove the break condition ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go with `time.sleep()` The parameter passed into this function is the exact number of seconds you can pause the program.

```
import time
time.sleep(5)  ## pauses for 5 seconds.
```

I don't know if I'm helping you right but you can try like the following if this is what you are looking for

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def print_time():
    var =10
    var = "fdfd"
    print "From print_time", time.time()
def print_some_times():
    print time.time()
    s.enter(5, 1, print_time, ())
    s.enter(10, 1, print_time, ())
    s.run()

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    print_some_times()
```

OUTPUT :

```
1418811191.3
From print_time 1418811196.31
From print_time 1418811201.3
1418811206.31
From print_time 1418811211.34
From print_time 1418811216.32
```

If you just want to call the function `print_time()` with delay of 5 seconds and forever then try the following

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def print_time():
    var =10
    var = "fdfd"
    print "From print_time", time.time()
def print_some_times():
    print time.time()
    s.enter(5, 1, print_time, ())
    s.enter(10, 1, print_time, ())
    s.run()

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    print_time()
```

OUTPUT :

```
From print_time 1418811465.18
From print_time 1418811470.2
From print_time 1418811475.27
From print_time 1418811480.27
From print_time 1418811485.27
```